How to fetch all the available channel list in Android/Google TV to iOS App?
Currently I am developing iOS TV remote App in Android/Google TV, In that app we have done TV pairing, photo/video casting, volume up/down, keyboard, etc. tasks.
Now we need to fetch all the available TV Channels from connected Android TV/Google TV SetupBox to our iOS application and display list of channel so user can able to change channel accordingly.
does anyone know about it like how to fetch Android TV channel list in iOS?
